# Buspirate_spi and flashrom opensource software

Tags: memory, flash

I have a question about buspirate_spi programmer and flashrom. I have a new Flash rom Boye BY25Q128AS similar to the winbond W25Q128.V in the flashrom list. How can I dump the data from this specific IC that not available in flashrom?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to edit flashchips.h and add BY25Q128AS jedec ID (RDID)
and recompile flashrom.
More info here: https://leo.leung.xyz/wiki/Flashrom

Cheap and quick alternative: CH341A usb programmer.